# How to prevent navbar hiding/collapsing on clicking a particular menu-item which has a dropdown class?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to prevent the navbar collapse on click the `About Us` section or `Projects` section in the following code. I have tried `event.stopPropagation()` on these two buttons, but when till the time the jQuery code executes, the navbar has already collapses and hides itself.

```
<li class="page-scroll">
   <a href="#home">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us<span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="aboutus.html">Vision</a></li>
      <li><a href="team.html">Founding Team</a></li>
      <!--<li><a href="donors.html">Members</a></li>-->
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="page-scroll">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="sample-campaign - vidya.html">Vidya Vistar</a></li>
      <li><a href="sample-campaign - safai.html">Safai Abhyaan</a></li>
      <li><a href="sample-campaign - clothes.html">Clothes Donation</a></li>
      <li><a href="sample-campaign - food.html">Food Donation</a></li>
      <li><a href="sample-campaign - onetime.html">Ad Hoc</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="page-scroll">
   <a href="#events">Events</a>
</li>
<li class="page-scroll">
   <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
</li>
<li class="page-scroll">
   <a href="#join">Get Involved</a>
</li>
```

How to prevent this hiding of navbar (on screen size less than `992px`) on clicking the `Projects` or `About Us` buttons?

Comment: can you add jsfiddle link with your js and css code?

Comment: I will in a while after my job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas, after 4 days of going through the code, I found the function that was being called during the click event of all the buttons, including the headers of subsections (`About Us` and `Projects`). This happens when you try to continue a project which was started by someone else. Here was the code:

```
$('.navbar li').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

I changed it to:

```
// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.toggle-responsive').click(function() {
    $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

And sepecified the classes where it should be called on:

```
<li class="page-scroll toggle-responsive">
   <a href="#home">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us<span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li class="toggle-responsive"><a href="aboutus.html">Vision</a></li>
      <li class="toggle-responsive"><a href="team.html">Founding Team</a></li>
      <!--<li><a href="donors.html">Members</a></li>-->
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="page-scroll">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li class="toggle-responsive"><a href="sample-campaign - vidya.html">Vidya Vistar</a></li>
      <li class="toggle-responsive"><a href="sample-campaign - safai.html">Safai Abhyaan</a></li>
      <li class="toggle-responsive"><a href="sample-campaign - clothes.html">Clothes Donation</a></li>
      <li class="toggle-responsive"><a href="sample-campaign - food.html">Food Donation</a></li>
      <li class="toggle-responsive"><a href="sample-campaign - onetime.html">Ad Hoc</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="page-scroll toggle-responsive">
   <a href="#events">Events</a>
</li>
<li class="page-scroll toggle-responsive">
   <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
</li>
<li class="page-scroll toggle-responsive">
   <a href="#join">Get Involved</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you can look. A little bit tricky solution. First i tried  bootstarp toogle event "hide.bs.popover" ( If you want , you can check http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) i cant do this way :(

I only use jquery Now it is works. Solution is very simple when you click "a" bootstrap open dropdown then add class "open" to "li" So i checked "li" class has "open" then i remove data-toogle attribute

```
 var elementAbout = $(".dropdown a");

elementAbout.click( function() {
    if($("li.dropdown").hasClass("open")){
    elementAbout.removeAttr("data-toggle")
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sercantimocin/v992z8er/3/

Answer (score 2):

Hope this is what you're trying to achieve, add `event` `hide.bs.dropdown` and usually we stop the event propagation by `event.stopPropagation();` and preventDefault is needed if any anchor or default action is bound to the element. Expecting the screen size to be less than `992px` have a check for screen width/heihgt as `if (screen.height < '992') { }` and then execute the `e.preventDefault(); and e.stopPropagation();`

```js
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul class="custom">
  <li class="page-scroll">
    <a href="#home">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Us<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="aboutus.html">Vision</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="team.html">Founding Team</a>
      </li>
      <!--<li><a href="donors.html">Members</a></li>-->
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="sample-campaign - vidya.html">Vidya Vistar</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="sample-campaign - safai.html">Safai Abhyaan</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="sample-campaign - clothes.html">Clothes Donation</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="sample-campaign - food.html">Food Donation</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="sample-campaign - onetime.html">Ad Hoc</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="page-scroll">
    <a href="#events">Events</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-scroll">
    <a href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page-scroll">
    <a href="#join">Get Involved</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```